# wx top level menubar event (python)

Tags: python, wxpython, menubar, wxwidgets

Is there any way in wxPython to capture a click on an item on the menubar without any childeren.

I.e. with menu structure

- File

  - Save
  - Quit
- Spam

I am able to capture events for clicking the save or quit item but am unsure on how I can capture the event for clicking spam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@uhz solution almost works, but I wouldn't recommend it. There must be a reason why clickable top-level menu items are not permitted. Under my environment (Debian, wx 2.8) his solution develops strange behavior, like triggering the event by hovering the item.
You're usecase is more the one of a toolbar, I suggest you use one here. One more time I can suggest a look a the [examples at zetcode](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/menustoolbars/) (section toolbars) if you're not familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand File and Spam are top menu items. On Windows you could try using `wx.EVT_MENU_OPEN` and filter events, for example:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.mixins.inspection import InspectionMixin

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)        
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()        
        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Save")
        fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "Quit")
        menuBar.Append(fileMenu, "File")
        self.__spamMenu = wx.Menu()
        menuBar.Append(self.__spamMenu, "Spam")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU_OPEN, self.__onSpamOpen)

    def __onSpamOpen(self, event):
        if event.GetMenu() != self.__spamMenu:
            return event.Skip()
        print "Spam clicked"

class MyMenuApp(wx.App, InspectionMixin):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.Init()
        frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, 'Frame Window Demo')
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyMenuApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

This works with Python 2.6 and wxPython 2.9.3.1

Comment: Nice try for a workaround, but this is not how it's gonna work. See my answer why this solution isn't really performing well. Did you encounter different behavior using your environment?

Comment: @uhz This worked on WinXPSP3 Python3.4.2 wxPython-Phoenix dev... it had to be frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU_OPEN, frame.OnMenuOpen) without any widgets or ids referenced in the Bind() call. Clicking directly on the MenuBar but no Menubar labels matters.